Maximum entropy probability law with constraints (symmetry and fixed mean)
For data generating purposes, I was wondering whether it was possible to find analytically a probability distribution over $\{-N,...,0,...,+N\}$ such that:

$\forall i, p_i + p_{-i} - \frac 2 {2N+1} = 0$  (i.e. the mean of $p_i$ and $p_{-i}$ follows a uniform distribution over $\{-N,...,0,...,+N\}$).
$\sum_{i=-N}^N ip_i = a$ with $a$ fixed within $\{-N,...,0,...,+N\}$.
$H(p) = -\sum_i p_i \log p_i$ is maximal (simply by simple of maximum entropy, I don't want to impose anything on the data I generate).

I've tried to use Lagrange multipliers to optimize under constraint, but I end up with this transcendental equation:
$$
1-\log p_i + 2\lambda \left(p_i - \frac 1 {2N+1}\right) + \mu i
$$
(With $\lambda$ and $\mu$ the Lagrange multipliers associated resp. to the first and second constraint of the list above).
I'm stuck here: it seems that one cannot solve such equation, but maybe it does simplify if one find the values of $\lambda$ or $\mu$. But I can't find a way to find those values in any satisfying manner.

I'm confused by the expression $p_i + p_{-i} + \frac{2}{2N+1} = 0$. The quantities $p_i$ and $p_{-i}$ are $\geq 0$, while $\frac{2}{2N+1} > 0$, so how can their sum be $0$? Also: Shouldn't there be a minus sign in your definition of $H(p)$?

@JohnBarber you're right thanks for noticing my mistakes. It was only typos, I fixed the signs!

Isn't the condition $p_i + p_{-i} - \frac{2}{2N+1} = 0$ actually $N$ constraints, so you should have $N$ multipliers $\lambda_i$? I think the $\lambda$ in your transcendental equation should be $\lambda_{|i|}$ for $i\neq 0$. Also: You should have another constraint that $\sum_i p_i = 1$.

We wish to maximize the entropy
$$
H(p) = -\sum_{i=-N}^N p_i \log p_i
$$
subject to two conditions:
$$
p_i + p_{-i} = \frac{2}{2N+1} \qquad\qquad (1)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=-N}^N i p_i = a \qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
$$
First of all, we note that condition (1) implies $p_0 = \frac{1}{2N+1}$, and also constrains the $p_i$ to satisfy the normalization condition $\sum_i p_i = 1$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=-N}^N p_i
&= p_0 + \sum_{i=1}^N(p_i + p_{-i})\\
&=\frac{1}{2N+1} + \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{2}{2N+1}\\
&= 1
\end{align}
Therefore we do not have to impose normalization as a separate constraint. Having fixed $p_0$, we are left with an optimization problem in $2N$ unknowns (the $p_i$ for $i\neq 0$), with $N+1$ constraints (condition (1) for $1\leq i\leq N$ and condition (2)). Using $N+1$ Lagrange multipliers, we will attempt to maximize the quantity
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = -\sum_{i=-N}^N p_i\log p_i + \sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_i\left(p_i+p_{-i} - \frac{2}{2N+1}\right) + \mu\left(\sum_{i=-N}^N i p_i - a\right)
\end{equation}
Setting the derivative of $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $p_j$ equal to $0$ for $j\neq 0$ yields:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dp_j} = -1 -\log p_j + \lambda_{|j|} + j\mu = 0
\end{equation}
This can be solved for $p_j$:
\begin{equation}
p_j = \frac1e e^{\lambda_{|j|} + j \mu} \qquad\qquad\qquad (3)
\end{equation}
Plugging (3) into constraint (1) yields
\begin{equation}
p_j + p_{-j} = \frac{2}{e}e^{\lambda_{|j|}}\cosh(j\mu) =\frac{2}{2N+1}
\longrightarrow \frac{1}{e}e^{\lambda_{|j|}} = \frac{1}{(2N+1)\cosh(j\mu)} \qquad (4)
\end{equation}
Combining (3) and (4) allows us to write $p_j$ in terms of $\mu$ alone:
\begin{equation}
p_j = \frac{e^{j\mu}}{(2N+1)\cosh(j\mu)} \qquad\qquad\qquad (5)
\end{equation}
Now plug (5) into constraint (2) and rearrange a little to arrive at:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^N j \tanh(j\mu) = \frac{a(2N+1)}{2} \qquad\qquad\qquad (6)
\end{equation}
Equation (6) is a transcendental equation for $\mu$ in terms of $N$ and $a$ which does not in general admit an analytic solution. Nevertheless, we can imagine solving it (numerically, for example) to yield a value of $\mu$, which can be plugged into (5) to obtain a solution to the original problem.
A few notes:

For the special case $a=0$, (6) implies that $\mu = 0$ and $p_j = \frac{1}{2N+1}$ for all $j$, a uniform distribution.

Since $-1 < \tanh(x) < +1$, the quantity $\sum_{j=1}^N j \tanh(j\mu)$ is bounded to lie in $\left(-\frac{N(N+1)}{2}, +\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\right)$. This implies that (6) has a real solution only for $a\in\left(-\frac{N(N+1)}{2N+1}, +\frac{N(N+1)}{2N+1}\right)$, which is in general not the full possible range of $a$ given in the original prompt.



thank you very much! that's exactly what I was looking for. The explanations are very clear, it teaches me a lot! :)
